# In Hibernate JPA: OneToMany while updating entity, how to overwrite default delete condition?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I observed, on update OneToMany relationship, first hibernate deletes the entries from child entity, then update new data in child entity. Is there any way to overwrite default delete query or is it possible?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PROFILE_ID")
    private Long profileId; 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CAND_USER_LANGUAGE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID"))
    private Set<LanguageMaster> language;
}
```

Set values in model:

```
Set<UserLanguage> languageSet = some set of UserLanguage;
UserProfile userProfile =  userProfileDao.findByLoginId(usrId);
BeanUtils.copyProperties(userProfile, form);
userProfile.setLanguage(languageSet);
userProfileDao.saveOrUpdate(userProfile);


@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_LANGUAGE")
public class UserLanguage {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    private Integer languageId;

    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private Long profileId;
}
```

Comment: post your code that is updating the child entities.

Comment: code snippet is added.

Comment: where is the update? You are persisting a new object `UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();` here i believe!!

Comment: Yes, userProfile is fetched from DB. I edited in question as well.

Comment: try this `userProfile.getLanguage().addAll(languageSet );`

Comment: Thanks, But this append languageSet  with old one. I am looking to play with hibernate default delete while updating.

Comment: So you want all the child that are detached should be deleted!!?? Did you try `orphanRemoval=true`